# Run multiple Meka (Weka) classifiers - load errors to file / table object

Tags: output, weka, multilabel-classification

For those of you unfamiliar with Meka - it is an extension of Weka for multi-label classifiers. Meka and Weka are VERY similar, however, and so Weka users may be able to answer this question, too.

Basically, I want my results from my runs of various classifiers, and I want them all in a table so I can do Model Selection quickly (dynamically/automatically) without having to hardcode the values from each classifier, for the various evaluation metrics...

Is there a fool-proof, effective way to run multiple classifier experiments - say using cross validation - and get a table like the below:

```
Model                    Hamming_Loss    Exact_match    Jaccard    One_Error    Rank_Loss
Binary.Relevance           0.94             0.95          0.03      0.04       0.002
Classifier.Chains          0.91             0.94          0.06      0.04       0.03
Random.k-Labelsets         0.95             0.97          0.01      0.01       0.005
...                        ...              ...           ...       ...
...                        ...              ...           ...       ...
```

Comment: As a general strategy, can't you use meka from the command line and extract the output yourself using command-line tools for text processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Java you can manually create an array of different classifiers and iterate along it, saving the relevant output values in a matrix, for easy acces afterwards. You may even create a new dataset from the results obtained, for dynamic model selection, as you stated. But the key point is, as said, that you have to set up your classifiers array manually.

```
Classifiers[] cls = new Classifiers[clSize];
cls[0] = new J48();//or whatever you need
...

//one option:
cls[0].buildClassifier(dataset);
....

//another option
cls[0].crossValidateModel(dataset);
....
```

Hope to have helped. Comment, if you need further support.

Comment: I assume you download java source files that contain the class structure right? It's been a while since I coded in Java, but setting it up is always the hardest part. Do you know of instructions for setting up a the Java development framework on various operating systems (Windows, Unix)?

Comment: It's a piece of cake. Download from Oracle the latest version of the co-bundle JDK+Netbeans, install and start coding. Only thing you have to take into account is to add a new library with the WEKA jar, in the project options (right-click, etc). You could use also other IDEs, like Eclipse, telling it where the JDK is installed, through options menu.